# delete rows from 4 tables in one single sql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete rows from 4 tables in one single SQL. The tables have foreign keys of one another. 
The D1 table looks like

```
id     name     age
1      mike      12
2      john      43
```

the D2 table looks like

```
id     D1_id    price    salary
4        1        12       50
11       2        14       100
```

the A1 table looks like

```
id     D1_id      text     date
 9       1         abc     12-dec  
188      1         xyz     12-dec
222      1         kya     12-dec
123      2         poq     13-dec
```

the C1 tables looks like

```
id     A1_id      label     date
124      9         pqr      12-dec
145      9         qwe      12-dec
121     222        fdg      13-dec
```

The SQL that  have tried till now

```
delete FROM D1,D2,A1,C1 INNER JOIN D2 on (D1.id = D2.D1_id) where name = 'mike'
```

So I need to delete the rows based on the name from D1 table. I can change the name and it should it delete all corresponding rows from all tables.

Is it possible to use on delete cascade ?http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5ed78/1

Comment: Whats your error? Can you not just delete them in reverse order of their foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

```
delete d1, d2, a1, c1
from d1
left join d2 on d1.id = d2.d1_id
left join a1 on d1.id = a1.d1_id
left join c1 on a1.id = c1.a1_id
where d1.name = 'mike'
```

Comment: @rkbom9: How do you execute this? Are you executing exactly this code or did you adjust it? If so post the real thing please.

Comment: exactly like this  delete document, document_content, artifact, classfication
from  document
left join document_content on document.id = document_content.document_id
left join artifact on document.id = artifact.document_id
left join classfication on artifact.id = classification.artifact_id
where document.doc_name LIKE 'SourceTest1';

Comment: I just changed the names of the table thats it